# Array contains into postgres jsonb with Spring data JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jsonb, spring-data-jdbc

Let's make a journey...

What I want to achieve is

`SELECT * FROM people WHERE interest->'interests' ?| ARRAY['sport','cars'];`

into my Repository defined as

```
public interface PeopleRepository extends CrudRepository<People, UUID> {
   @Query("SELECT * FROM people where interest->'interests' ??| :array::text[] ")
   List<People> findByInterest(@Param("array") String interest);
```

and finally select interests, using the method in this way

```
findByInterest("{foo, beer}")
```

This is what I achieved after a day of tests and
IMHO is really **MEH**

I think out of there, a nicest solution is possible
(without sql cast and string concatenation in runtime)

Could you help with a more "clean code" solution?
(Sorry, for the long post)

**Update**

I will elaborate a little bit better my question.
I'm searching for something like

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM people where interest->'interests' ??| :array::text[] ")
List<People> findByInterest(@Param("array") List<String> interest);
```

is this possible ?

Comment: It's easily possible in plain JDBC, don't know about Spring though. Does it work if you declare the Java parameter as an array, e.g. `findByInterest(@Param("array") String[] interest);` and use `??| :array` in the query?

Comment: That's is strange! 
I tested it out, and using the `String[]` no error during compilation, but in runtime no result will be retrieved, what da hell...
But honestly also if this solution would work, I think we deserve a better code for this kind of stuff

Comment: Well, it's quite easy in plain JDBC

Comment: Is it working? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON array elements strores data in the following way

{
"interests" : ["sport", "cars"]

}

So if you directly java list it does not work, so one option is convert java array into a string which can be looked at as json array like ["sport", "cars"] or
use jsonObject used to create json array like below

```
JSONArray interests = new JSONArray();
a.add(0, "sport");
a.add(0, "car");

findByInterest(interests.toString())

@Query("SELECT * FROM people where interest->'interests' ??| :array::text[] ")
List<People> findByInterest(@Param("array") String interest);
```